# Non-Jewish missionary on Mi Yodeya

Tags: discussion

Recently I noticed that there's a user "Rabbi Michael Tzadok" on Mi Yodeya, who doesn't seem to have been active for a good number of years, but nevertheless appears to be the same person as Thomas Elk (aka Michael Elkohen), [the exposed missionary who pretended to be an Orthodox Jew in Eretz Yisroel](https://www.thejc.com/news/israel/exclusive-unmasked-the-christian-missionary-who-went-undercover-as-an-orthodox-rabbi-1.516346).

Considering this person is a non-Jew, and a xtian to boot, I think there's some danger in letting his entries remain on Mi Yodeya. Perhaps his entries can be removed?